# React native share function on ios not share the right content

Tags: ios, react-native, share, native

React native IOS Share.
When i use share function on ios, the application share all application file and not the words passed by message parameter.
Help?

```
Share.share({
    message: ('' + this.props.words),
    url: '',
    title: title
}, {
    dialogTitle: title,
    excludedActivityTypes: [
        'com.apple.UIKit.activity.PostToTwitter'
    ],
});
```

Comment: Add your code and try in post

Comment: Share.share({
                    message: ('' + this.props.words),
                    url: '',
                    title: title
                }, {
                    // Android only:
                    dialogTitle: title,
                    // iOS only:
                    excludedActivityTypes: [
                        'com.apple.UIKit.activity.PostToTwitter'
                    ],
                });

Comment: sorry, i didn't undestand

Comment: Update your post